# Garmin fenix 3 native colors

Tags: garmin

I have a Garmin fenix 3 (non-HR) watch.  My understanding is that it uses the 16 color palette:  https://developer.garmin.com/index.php/blog/post/pro-tip-using-the-bitmap-palette-options  There apparently is an exception to the color purple for the fenix 3: https://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/Graphics.html

Actually, there are only 14 colors plus transparent, but I digress.

When I create a simple design made of blocks of each of those 14 colors and set it as my watch face, I expect the colors to be solid and not dithered or filled with dots to attempt to make the color look like a color that can't actually be displayed.  I created the file as a .png with GIMP and used the Garmin Face-It app to create the watch face from my png file.

When on my watch, the only colors that are solid are 0x000000 (black), 0xffffff (white), 0x0000ff (blue), 0x00aaff (light blue), 0x00ff00 (light green), and 0xff00ff (pink).  The other colors have varying numbers of dots in them.  The red and dark red colors show up as a dithered gray.

My question is:  are those not the correct native colors for the fenix 3 or is the Face-It app changing them when it shouldn't?

Comment: Hi @huhqwerty. Are you using the exact color codes from the documentation? It's been a while since I coded in this, but I remember that if your color was just a small bit off, it would try and blend (very badly using the 16 colors available) to the color you have assigned. Yellow, orange and red are very close to each other in my mind.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the exact hex codes listed in the documentation, including the exception for purple.  My guess is that the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what exactly how bad it is what you are seeing. I have just tried it in code to exactly draw those 12 colors on my 920 (which should have a very similar display to the fenix 3).

[image: 920 xT color rendering]

If you are looking closely you can definitively easily discern the single pixels, but those garmin watches don't really have the highest resolution, so it's probably not really surprising.

[image]

So if you are seeing that kind of "dithering" It's probably normal.

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me post photos so I can't show you how it looks but in the Face-It app, there is a light red (0xFF0000) and dark red (0xAA0000) that show up as light gray and dark gray on my Fenix watch.  All of the other colors look pretty close with varying degrees of dithering.